# Failed to Login as 'Domain\ComputerName' pyodbc with py2exe

Tags: python, sql-server, py2exe, pyodbc

Ok so I have a script that connects to a mssql db and i need to run as a service which I have already accomplished but when I run it as a service it overrides my credentials that I have put in when i connect to the db with the ad computer account.

It runs perfect when i run it on its own and not as a service.

My Connection String is:

`'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDB;UID=DOMAIN\myusername;PWD=A;Trusted_Connection=True'`

The Error is:

`Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME')`

Any Advice?

Comment: What is your ODBC connection string? What error messages you see in the event log?

Comment: 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVERNAME;DATABASE=DBName;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=True'

Comment: Login failed for user 'CORE\\DEEPTHOUGHT$

Comment: You probably should mention the version of MSSQL server you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following connection string will use Windows authentication, using the account running the service to authenticate with the database. Change the service account to one that has database access:

`'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVERNAME;DATABASE=DBName;Trusted_Connection=yes'`

To change service account:

- Start -> Run -> services.msc
- Right-click service -> Properties
- Log On tab
- OK/Apply to save changes

[image: Screenshot of window to change service account]

Comment: theunilife mentioned 'overrides my credentials' in the question. He want to use the 'RunAs' credential in the job. It implies he want to use trusted connection.

Comment: @AnthonyKong I interpreted it as he wanted to use the `UID` and `PWD` values...either way my answer is updated to include both methods for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

In the last project I worked on, I found that `DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVERNAME;DATABASE=DBName` is sufficient to initiate a db connection in trusted mode.

If it still does not work, it is probably either

1) the account `DEEPTHOUGHT`  on mssql server is not set up properly.

2) the runAs in the service is not set up properly (why error message mentions 'ComputerName' instead of 'DEEPTHOUGHT'?)