# Error 28000: Login failed for user DOMAIN\\user with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to use Python to connect to a SQL database by using Window authentication. I looked at some of the posts here (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000256/failed-to-login-as-domain-computername-pyodbc-with-py2exe)), but the suggested methods didn't seem to work.

For example, I used the following code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
                      server='SERVERNAME', 
                      database='DATABASENAME',               
                      trusted_connection='yes')
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft]
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\username'. 
(18456)")
```

(*Note that I replaced the actual domain name and user name with `DOMAIN` and `username` respectively, in the error message above.*)

I also tried using my `UID` and `PWD`, which led to the same error.

Lastly, I tried to change the service account by following the suggestion from the link above, but on my computer, there was no `Log On` tab when I went to the `Properties` of `services.msc`.

I wonder what I did wrong and how I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 41):

**Connecting from a Windows machine:**

With Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server, `Trusted_connection=yes` tells the driver to use "Windows Authentication" and your script will attempt to log in to the SQL Server using *the Windows credentials of the user running the script*. `UID` and `PWD` cannot be used to supply alternative Windows credentials in the connection string, so if you need to connect as some other Windows user you will need to use Windows' [RUNAS](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command to run the Python script as that other user..

If you want to use "SQL Server Authentication" with a specific *SQL Server login* specified by `UID` and `PWD` then use `Trusted_connection=no`.

**Connecting from a non-Windows machine:**

If you need to connect from a non-Windows machine and the SQL Server is configured to only use "Windows authentication" then Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server will require you to use Kerberos. Alternatively, you can use FreeTDS ODBC, specifying `UID`, `PWD`, and `DOMAIN` in the connection string, provided that the SQL Server instance is configured to support the older NTLM authentication protocol.

Comment: Is there a way to connect as another Windows User who is different to the one logged in?

Comment: @Gord Thompson, what do you mean with RUNAS here ?

Comment: Sandeep - if the item is a stored procedure, it is possible to create an "Execute As" statement within the stored procedure that allows the query to run using pre-defined credentials.

Answer (score 7):

I tried everything and this is what eventually worked for me:

```
import pyodbc
driver= '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    Trusted_Connection='Yes',
    Driver='{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}',
    Server='MyServer,1433',
    Database='MyDB'
)
```

Comment: that worked! for {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} (SQL Express 2019) I had to remove the port number to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this cxn string:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;PORT=1433;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
```

http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/

Comment: I assume I should replace `localhost` with the actual server name? Either way, I got errors...

Comment: This Worked !! Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft's ODBC drivers do not use a Port= parameter. If you need to connect to a port other than the default (1433) you must append it to the Server argument with a comma, e.g.,
`Server      = mydbserver.mycompany.com,49242`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue while connecting to the default database (MSSQLSERVER). If you are connecting to the default database, please remove the

> *database='DATABASENAME',*

line from the connection parameters section and retry.

Cheers,
Deepak

Comment: MSSQLSERVER is the (database) server instance name, not the database name.  A SQL Server instance can contain many databases but you will nearly always want to include the database name in the connection string so you are not hard coding the database name in individual queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Import Library:

```
import pyodbc # pyodbc library
```

## Credentials:

```
server_info='server'
driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
database_info='database'
user_info='username'
password_info='password'
```

## Establish a connection to the "server" database

```
connection_str = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server_info};DATABASE={database_info};UID={user_info};PWD={password_info};TrustServerCertificate=yes'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

## Feel free to call sql queries:

```
sql_query = "SELECT * from table"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

Comment: `TrustServerCertificate=yes` saved me.

Answer (score 0):

The first option works if your credentials have been stored using the command prompt. The other option is giving the credentials (UId, Psw) in the connection.

The following worked for me:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=yourServer;DATABASE=yourDatabase;UID=yourUsername;PWD=yourPassword')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyodbc   #For python3 MSSQL

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"   #For Connection
                   "Server=192.168.0.***;"
                   "PORT=1433;"
                   "Database=***********;"
                   "UID=****;"
                   "PWD=********;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()                        #Cursor Establishment
cursor.execute('select site_id from tableName')   #Execute Query

rs = cursor.fetchall() 
print(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different use case than the OP, but for those interested it is possible to connect to a MS SQL Server database using Windows Authentication for a different user account than the one logged in.

This can be achieved using the python jaydebeapi module with the JDBC JTDS driver. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376100/create-a-jtds-connection-string-in-python/58653014#58653014) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you may need to change the authentication mechanism.  For example, my database is using ADP.  So my connection looks like this

```
pyodbc.connect(
    Trusted_Connection='No',
    Authentication='ActiveDirectoryPassword',
    UID=username,
    PWD=password,
    Driver=driver,
    Server=server,
    Database=database)
```

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory)

Answer (score -1):

`Trusted_connection=no` did not helped me. When i removed entire line and added `UID`, `PWD` parameter it worked. My takeaway from this is remove

Comment: Removing Trusted_connection entirely is equivalent to Trusted_connection=no so there should be no difference in performance.