# Connect SQL Server from python with different domain and trusted_connection=true

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

Connect SQL Server from python with different domain and trusted_connection=true. Is there any way we can achieve this? If i say trusted_connection=no and pass the user name and password it fails with login failed error because my organization will not allow the trusted_connection as no. Is there any way we can achieve this? Please advise

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54776235/383793) looks very similar, maybe its comments are of use to you?

Comment: Also from the [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki) I understand that it differs whether you connect from a Windows machine or some other OS. It looks like you can only use `trusted_connection` from Windows, as it uses your windows credentials. But I have no experience with that. I'm just reading the docs. :) Good luck.

Comment: So you're connecting to a Windows server from a Windows workstation on a different domain. Is that correct?