# Create a jTDS connection string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, connection-string, jtds

I'm trying to establish a jTDS connectivity using Python. Can anyone please help me in accomplishing that?

From the SQL Server, I generally connect using the below connection string:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBServer:port/DBInstance;useNTLMv2=true;domain=Domain
```

I'm trying to do as below in Python:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DBName,port;'
                      'Database=database;'
                      'Truster_Connection=yes;'
                      'uid=user;'
                      'pwd=password;'
                )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * from Table')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Error:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USER'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USER'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)"))
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37702329/1106952 Specifically: you can't use uid and pwd with Trusted_Connection parameter

Answer (score 7):

If you are specifically trying to connect to MS SQL Server using jTDS as opposed to ODBC, then you can use the jaydebeapi python package.

See the following code (Python 3):

```py
import sys
import jaydebeapi


def main():
    try:
        # jTDS Driver.
        driver_name = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"

        # jTDS Connection string.
        connection_url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server_hostname>:<port>/<database_name>"

        # jTDS Connection properties.
        # Some additional connection properties you may want to use
        # "domain": "<domain>"
        # "ssl": "require"
        # "useNTLMv2": "true"
        # See the FAQ for details http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html
        connection_properties = {
            "user": "username",
            "password": "password",
        }

        # Path to jTDS Jar
        jar_path = "<path_to>\\jtds-1.3.1.jar"

        # Establish connection.
        connection = jaydebeapi.connect(driver_name, connection_url, connection_properties, jar_path)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Execute test query.
        cursor.execute("select 1 as test_connection")
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        if res:
            print(str(res))  # Should print [(1,)]

    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Prior to this, you need to complete the following:

1. Download and install JDK/JRE from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. pip install jaydebeapi or download from [here](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi)
3. Download jtds from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)
4. Update connection_url, connection_properties, jar_path.

Comment: You may have to add the jar location to the CLASSPATH for this to work.