# django-mssql-backend - Invalid connection string attribute (0)

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure, django-mssql-backend

OK, I'm slowly going crazy. I want to connect Django 3 to MSSQLv15 Server. Connection works if I use Trustedconnection=yes (using win credentials), it also works on Ubuntu if I'm using FreeTDS v7.4 but it won't work in Windows if I manually insert service account or personal credentials and use sql login. Is it some kind of dependency issue? I have tried various library version combos, but to no avail.

***Error message is:***

```
conn = Database.connect(connstr,
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\user'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")
```

***Requiremetns.txt***

```
asgiref              3.3.4
Django               3.2
django-mssql-backend 2.8.1
djangorestframework  3.12.4
pip                  20.2.3
pyodbc               4.0.30
pytz                 2021.1
setuptools           49.2.1
sqlparse             0.4.1
```

**Not working (Win)**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'hostname',
        'USER': 'DOMAIN\\user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'PORT': '1433',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
           }
        }
    }
```

**Working (Win)**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'hostname',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT': '1433',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'Trusted_Connection': 'yes',
           }
        }
    }
```

***Working (Ubuntu)***

```
django==2.1.0
django-pyodbc-azure-2019

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'hostname',
        'USER': 'DOMAIN\\user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'PORT': '1433',

            'OPTIONS': {
                "driver": "FreeTDS",
                "host_is_server": True,
                "extra_params": "tds_version=7.4",

               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: _use service account or personal credentials without Trustedconnection_ What does that mean? Either you use a windows account and set the trusted connection option or you use a sql login and don't set that option (or set it to No). If you don't set that option i believe the default is "not set (No)" - meaning you are using a sql login.

Comment: Yep "without Trustedconnection" is unnessacery here. I meant that trusted connection works and sql login with manual credentials doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server doesn't seem to support authenticating domain users via username and password, where FreeTDS does (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37702329/9461432).  On a non-Windows machine, Microsoft directs you [to use Kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15).

Authenticating via username & password works fine if you're connecting to a user that uses SQL Server authentication (ie. non-domain).

Comment: Ah then the mystery is solved. Well, at least I can use domain user in Docker with FreeTDS. Thanks for helping out!